# How to capture the camera View with video capture card?

Tags: video, camera, webcam, emgucv

I have a problem which is related to EmguCV to capture the camera view.
My code is below :

```
Public _capture As Capture
Dim wr As Double
Public _capture As Capture
Dim wr As Double
Dim hr As Double
Dim rtg As Rectangle
Dim _IsOpen As Boolean

Public Sub OpenCamera(selcetCamNum As Integer)
    Try
        If _capture Is Nothing Then
            selectNum = selcetCamNum
            Me._capture = New Capture(selcetCamNum)
            wr = 1
            hr = 1
            rtg = New Rectangle(CInt(105 * wr), CInt(155 * hr), CInt(110 * wr), CInt(50 * hr))
            AddHandler Me._capture.ImageGrabbed, AddressOf ProcessFrame
            Me._IsOpen = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("OpenCamera" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub CameraStart()
    If Me._capture IsNot Nothing Then
        If Me._IsStart = False Then
            'start the capture
            Me._capture.Start()
            Me._IsStart = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I use the usb webcam,and it can be executed successfully, but when I use video capture card(UPMOST-UPG301PB V), it can not be executed successfully, And I insert the break point inside the code, there's no any errors in it. The version of emgu is 2.4.10. Could anybody answer me how to solve the problem??

Comment: any error message? in windows openCV there is a tiny bug in the VideoInput library. Can you use the capture card with applications like VLC, skype, etc?

Comment: There's no any error messqage, and I use the capture card with TeamViewer, the camera can't capture anything, but I use the PowerDirector software to open my camera, it can capture successfully.

Comment: in TeamViewer it doesn't work? probably the card doesnt hold some standard but powerdirector uses some deeper knowledge

Comment: Hello Micka,do you know what's the detail of the tiny bug in OpenCV?, and do you any idea if I still using the same card, just adjust my code?

Comment: the bug isn't in OpenCV but in VideoInput library which is used by OpenCV. It is in OpenCV: `sources/modules/highgui/src/cap_dshow.cpp` there is a line: `hr = VD->pCaptureGraph->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, &MEDIATYPE_Video, VD->pVideoInputFilter, VD->pGrabberF, VD->pDestFilter);` change it to `hr = VD->pCaptureGraph->RenderStream(&CAPTURE_MODE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, VD->pVideoInputFilter, VD->pGrabberF, VD->pDestFilter);` and recompile openCV etc...

Comment: HI Micka, Thanks for your answer, do you know what file lib the opencv cap_dshow.cpp in Emgucv ?? could I just adjust the code in emgucv ?

Comment: sorry, no experience in EmguCV at all...

Comment: OK, Thank you very much,Micka :)